# How can I exclude files from PHP glob function, that contain a specific word and number in the filename

Tags: php

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I have a directory with some php files and a subdirectory which contains php files with the same name, but with a number before them. This number is used elsewhere for sorting the files. Like this:

```
folder
├── subfolder
|   ├── 001_file.php
|   └── 002_anotherfile.php
|   └── 003_onemorefile.php
├── file.php
├── anotherfile.php
├── onemorefile.php
```

What I would like to do is to include a random file from the subdirectory into a file from the root directory, but the included file can not contain the same name.

This is my code:

```
$excludefile = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
'/folder/subfolder/*' . basename(__FILE__));

$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
'/folder/subfolder/*.php');

$fileswithexclusion = array_values(array_diff($files, $excludefile));

$file = array_rand($fileswithexclusion);

include $fileswithexclusion[$file];
```

When I do not try to dynamically generate the excludefile, it works. Like this:

```
$excludefile = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
'/folder/subfolder/001_file.php');
```

So to solve my problem I would need a way to correctly generate the $excludefile (with the number)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sortedDir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'subfolder';

$files = glob($sortedDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.php');

$filteredFiles = array_filter($files, function($file) {
    return false === strpos($file, basename(__FILE__));
});

$fileToInclude = $filteredFiles[array_rand($filteredFiles)];

print $fileToInclude;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code you provided indeed shows a random block, exactly the same as my code did, but it still does not exclude the file which contains the same name...

Comment: I thought it did ... oh well... :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

Shoud work, "index.php" as sample file to exclude

```
$files = array_filter(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/subfolder/*.php'), function($v) {
    return false === strpos($v, 'index.php');
});
```

**Update**
To get filename dynamically you can use code below

```
$info = pathinfo($file);
$file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This already simplified my code. But I still can't "dynamically" tell which file to exclude based on the filename. I tried it like this now:

        $files = array_filter(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
        '/folder/subfolder/*.php'), function($v) {
        return false === strpos($v, basename(__FILE__));
        });

But that still leaves the number that is not generated in this case.

Comment: @DavyMeykens if my answer was useful pls mark it as useful and the best

Comment: Thanks again Marat, for your help. But this still doesn't solve my problem. When I use it like this, it will exclude file.php in stead of 001_file.php. Probably I'm doing something wrong here :) – the file that may not be included should be " 'Anynumber_' . basename(__FILE__) . '.php' "

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to following:

```
$excludefile = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
'/folder/subfolder/[0-9]*' . basename(__FILE__));

$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
'/folder/subfolder/*.php');

$fileswithexclusion = array_values(array_diff($files, $excludefile));

$file = array_rand($fileswithexclusion);

include $fileswithexclusion[$file];
```

The reason your code is not working is because you are using * which matches everything in

```
$excludefile = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/folder/subfolder/*' .basename(__FILE__));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I thought this would be the solution, but the file that should be excluded keeps showing up...

Comment: @DavyMeykens, check my new solution. I have tested it. It works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again. I seriously don't know what's going wrong :) Everything works, but the file that should be excluded keeps showing up...

Comment: @DavyMeykens, just copy my code again, it should work and try to echo $excludefile and $files to see the files.

Comment: Well i did... I've used exactly your code, and the excludefile keeps showing up. I believe something is wrong with generating the number. Because when I try to include or echo only the includefile in stead of the other files, nothing shows... If you have any other ideas you are welcome of course. but thanks already for your help